# Elasticsearch ignoring must_not when sorting geo_query

Tags: elasticsearch

This query returns the first record with the `uuid` in the `must_not` clause.

When the sorting is removed the document with that `uuid` is not on the list, but I get random results as and I want them to be sorted by location asc (which seems to include)

Using 6.0 api version.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "geo_distance": {
            "location": {
              "lat": -33,
              "lon": 151
           },
            "distance": "100km"
          }
        },
        "must_not": {
            "term": {
            "uuid": "a3330c1a-8a24-4c7f-ad97-16ac5bd73e3f"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sort": [
     {
        "_geo_distance": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -33,
            "lon": 151
          },
          "order": "asc",
          "unit": "km",
          "mode": "min",
          "distance_type": "arc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "size": 10
}
```

#### First result

```
{
"took": 17,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "skipped": 0,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 1504,
  "max_score": null,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "myindex",
      "_type": "mytype",
      "_id": "a3330c1a-8a24-4c7f-ad97-16ac5bd73e3f",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "latitude": -33,
        "longitude": 151,
        "uuid": "a3330c1a-8a24-4c7f-ad97-16ac5bd73e3f",
        "location": [
          151,
          -33
        ]
      },
      "sort": [
        0
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you post your mappings? Get /<you_index>/_mappings ? Have you try to replace in your query uuid with _id ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your *uuid* field map as text or keyword? Check the [Why doesn’t the term query match my document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) section.

There are two solutions:

1) change your query to this:

```
 "must_not": {
        "term": {
            "uuid.keyword": "a3330c1a-8a24-4c7f-ad97-16ac5bd73e3f"
      }
    }
```

or 2) define your uuid field as **keyword** instead of text:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
     "mytype": {
        "properties": {
           "uuid": {
              "type":  "keyword"
            }
         }
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I had the mapping of uuid as a `text` I changed to keyword and it is working now.Thanks @Eirini Graonidou